# Is there a better way to access transients using javascript

Tags: ajax, javascript, transient, wp-localize-script

I've been searching around the web trying to find a better way to use WordPress transients with javascript. Currently I am using admin-Ajax to run a php function that retrieves the transient and returns it. This works fine but I'm curios to know if there is a more effective way of accessing that data without the overhead of using ajax and php.

I know I could probably do this using `wp_localize_script()` but I'm not sure if that method is any better that my current solution. Hopefully there is an expert out there that can help me with this.

Comment: Which method is the best depends on what the purpose is. What the script does? How do you use the data from transients in JavaScript? In general, if the transient is very small in size and it is always used in the page, I would use `wp_localize_script()` (or any proper method to send the data within the document).

Comment: I'm using system cron to collect external data and store it every 2 minutes. It then builds a wp query relating to the new data and stores it in a transient. 

On the front end, I have a feed that auto refreshes every 30 seconds. I'm using js to compare the transients for changes. If they are duplicates I can skip the need to rebuild the page. If they don't match i.e. the transient is different or it is expired or broken, I rebuild the page.

What I'm doing is reducing unnecessary work by detecting duplicates. I'm just not sure if this is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Transients should be used for short (for varying definition of it) time caching, and they are **by design** not reliable. From your description it sound like you are using them in a manner they were not designed to support and therefor probably the "best" for you is to not use transients at all.

Comment: My need for them is short term and I don't need them to be reliable. I'm using them to compare duplicate wp queries and saving work if they match. I don't need an entry to last longer than 2 minutes so I figured something that needs to expire is the perfect use for transients. If I'm wrong and short term storage use of transients is incorrect, then what is an example of the appropriate use for them?
I replied above if you care to read it, thanks for taking the time here.

Comment: It is hard to understand from your description but if you are going to ping the server every two minutes than transients are not your biggest design issue. Anyway, transients are not reliable which mean they are not reliable, you should not assume that they will hold a value for even 2 minutes especially if you use object caching of any kind.

Comment: Thanks for your words but you're not actually answering my question.

Comment: Since you asked for "best", the answer is that the best solution is to redesign you code.